# put icons under Resources subfolder

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

When I tried to archive one of my iOS projects, I got this warning message:

```
Validate MyApp.app ...in ....
Icon specified in the Info.plist not found under the top level app wrapper: Images/icon.png
```

I have put all images files under Resources/Images and created folder reference to Images folder in the project. What value I should give to Info.plist for icons images under a folder reference?

[image: Resources folder]

This is my current values:

[image]

Comment: Would it be acceptable to set up a group reference instead of a folder reference and just use base names?

Comment: Also, I believe your icons should be named starting with CapitalLetters.

Comment: I used to do that. But I just wonder if I can use folder reference for icons.

Comment: Is it required to have Captial Letters for icons?

Comment: I think it is required as [this document](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#qa/qa1686/_index.html) suggests.

Comment: Although I think capital letter is not the cause for this warning message, I will go ahead and try it.

Comment: I agree, I don't think it is the cause. Good idea though.

Comment: UPDATE: After updated all icon.png to Icon.png and ituensartowork.png to iTunesArtwork, the warning is still there.

Comment: See updated answer below.  Unless you just skipped itunesartwork.png in the screenshot, it seems to be missing from the folder.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that folder reference is setup properly.  This can happen when the folder path is not specified correctly in relation to the project folder.

Just noticed, where is the itunesartwork.png file?  I see it listed in your plist, but not in the folder.

Comment: I created a folder reference to Images folder. I think I did right cause there is no problem when build the project for DEBUG.

Comment: Where is the Image directory in relationship, though, to the .xcodeproj file in the filesystem hierarchy?  In my experience, this error when encountered on archiving, can often be resolved by: (1) moving the required icon files to the same filesystem level as the actual project file and (2) scrupulously following all of the documentation about naming, case-sensitivity, etc.